# How to implement multiple payment destinations in Stripe Checkout

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am fairly new to programming and was trying to create a marketplace checkout using stripe. I implemented stripe checkout already, however, to make it fully functional, I have to send multiple different accounts different amounts of money based on what products the customer has bought. I was wondering what is the best way to accomplish this was. I currently have the code below which only pays the seller of the first product the full amount:

```
router.post('/create-checkout-session', async(req, res) => {
  const {cartItems} = req.body
  const cartPriceArray = (cartItems.map((item) => {
        return {price: item.stripePriceId, quantity: 1}
  }))

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      line_items: cartPriceArray,
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}checkout-success`,
      cancel_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}cart`,
      payment_intent_data: {
        application_fee_amount: 1, // change to percentage in future
        transfer_data: {
          destination: cartItems[0].stripeAccountId,
        },
      },
    });
    console.log(session)
    res.json({url: session.url});
  });
```

I was wondering if I can create an array of payment intents within the destination or after that send the stripe price Id of each item to the stripe acc id of the seller who is selling each item(attached to the cart items being passed in). If this is not possible, what is the best and easiest way to achieve this? (The accounts are express accounts)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes an array of (Payment Intent and destination account) could work, that you are basically doing multiple [Destination Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges). But you can also do [Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers), which to do one Payment and multiple Transfers to different Connected Accounts.

Note that in Checkout Session you have corresponding parameter to implement Destination Charge [transfer_data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=curl#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-transfer_data) or Separate Charges and Transfers [transfer group](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=curl#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-transfer_group).

It's outlined in [Connect use cases](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#separate-charges-transfers):

> You can transfer funds to multiple connected accounts.

> A one-to-many
> relationship. For example, a payment made to a delivery service needs
> to be split between the store (the source of the items being
> delivered) and the delivery person.

Comment: Thank you! I will try out both and see which one works best for me.

Comment: How do you actually go about taking the payment then transferring it to multiple destinations? (note it's multiple seller, ie. items in basket that belong to more than one seller).